# iPhone/iPad simulator not lauching in Titanium studio 2.1.2

Tags: ios, titanium

I have following s/w configuration-

Mac- 10.6.8 with 2 GB ram installed over VMWare.
xcode- 4.2
Titanium studio- 2.1.2
Titanium sdk version - 3.0.0 GA and 2.1.2GA.

My problem is that when create a project with either 3.0.0 GA or 2.1.2GA, for android everything is fine. But iPhone or iPad simulator not lauching, if same code open in xcode and run then it working. We get following log info when run project for iPhone -

```
[INFO] One moment, building ...
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 2.1.2 (08/24/12 14:46 ed7f777)
[INFO] iPhone Device family: universal
[INFO] iPhone SDK version: 5.0
[INFO] iPhone simulated device: iphone
[INFO] Minimum iOS version: 4.0
[INFO] Compiling localization files
```

After that nothing happened.

Please give me solution.
Thank you....

Comment: Can you Share some your code  or demo Code.
what r u doing in coding....

Comment: I made simple single window default application, did not code anything from my side. Same project run for android.All android apps running, problem in only iPhone apps

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this?